# Insert a div inside an anchor removing the anchor styling in the div elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the whole div clickable, but removing any styling that the anchor adds to the div. I cannot use JS for this.

HTML code

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
  <div class="style1">
    <div class="style2">
      <div class="style3_">
        <div>
          <div class="text1">
            Here is the Text 1
          </div>
          <span class="text2">
            Here is the text 2
          </span>
        </div>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
          Link
        </a>   
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS code:

```
.style1 {
  padding: 16px;
}

.style2 {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  box-shadow: none
}

.style3 {
  display: flex;
  padding: 16px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.text1 {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: .00625rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.text2 {
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: .75rem;
  letter-spacing: .025rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: You have a link (i.e. an `a` tag) *inside*  another link/`a` tag. That's invalid HTML, plus it won't work as two links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` tags usually adds an underline to indicate that it is a link, that's actually just a text decoration, to remove that you can add `text-decoration: none;` to whatever class you want the style to be removed, or you can add that to the anchor tag directly. See the snippet below for your reference:

```css
.style3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dadce0;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 16px;
  width: max-content;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.text1 {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: .00625rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.text2 {
  line-height: 1rem;
  font-size: .75rem;
  letter-spacing: .025rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
  <div class="style3">
    <div>
      <div class="text1">
        Here is the Text 1
      </div>
      <span class="text2">
        Here is the text 2
      </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      Link
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I make sure that the whole box, created with border, is clickable?

Comment: you have another anchor tag inside of your anchor tag that have the same website reference, is that necessary? if not, change it to another `html tag` like `div`.

Comment: I can change it to another html tag. Is there a css trick to make all the content inside the box (border: 1px solid #dadce0;) clickable?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 Yes, you can use `flex: 1;` shorthand for `flex-grow: 1;` to make the anchor tag stretch its width to all available space. I've also simplified your code since you don't need the multiple containers to have the same result. Check my edit for reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does the anotherLink class do? I didn't get this part

Comment: Also, is there a way to make the whole box the size of its content? I do not want it to take the whole scene/div

Comment: Oh it was supposed to align the last link to the far-right, but since I fixed the `.style3` class naming issue I forgot to delete it when I finished the edit.

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 you can definitely do that, you can use `max-content` when setting the `width` and `height` of your class `style3`. I added a `gap` to add some spacing. I've edited the snippet, check it for your reference.